# How to read bytes from [u8; _] as u32 in reverse order?

Tags: arrays, memory, rust, endianness

I have [this code](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=cd60d5579e3a3690b81b025285a4d399):

```rust
let x:     [u8; 4]  = [0b10111011, 0b00110110, 0b11100010, 0b00010001];
let mut y: [u32; 1] = [0];
    
unsafe {
    std::ptr::copy(x.as_ptr() as *const u32, y.as_mut_ptr(), 1);
}
    
println!("{:b}", y[0]);
```

The print statement outputs `10001111000100011011010111011`, which means `y[0]` is getting read in the reverse order I need it. I want `y` to basically just be `[0b10111011_00110110_11100010_00010001]`.

I know this has to do with endianness, but I don't know how to achieve this.

Comment: See [u32::from_be_bytes](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.u32.html#method.from_be_bytes) and [u32::from_le_bytes](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.u32.html#method.from_le_bytes) methods.

Comment: Just a caveat: this call to `std::ptr::copy` is UB, because `[u8; 4]` has an alignment of 1, and `[u32; 1]` has an alignment of 4. There are various safe ways to achieve what you are trying to do, I think, but if you **do** need to do raw pointer mangling, use `std::ptr::write_unaligned` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is indeed because of your computer storing and reading integers in little endian byteorder, but you specified `x` in big endian fashion.

Try using [u32::from_be_bytes()](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.u32.html#method.from_be_bytes) which avoids the `unsafe` block and always converts `x` into the correct `u32` representation, whether on a little or big endian machine.

```rust
let y = u32::from_be_bytes(x)
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=d553eb0c7fe1d8fd7e95e523c731f14d)